# i want to implement div scrollbar relative to window scrollbar

Tags: php, jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

I want to implementing tyniscrollbar to my div element in form . 
 I want to make it synchronous with window scrollbar ,so that  when it will reach at the bottum of the page window scrollbar should automatically scroll-down with div scroll bar so that i can see all content of my div , please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but this should do the trick

```
var heightDiv = document.getElementById('#div1').clientHeight;
var height = document.body.offsetHeight;

jQuery(document).scroll(function(){

    var moved = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var ratio = moved*heightDiv/height;
    jQuery('#div1').animate({scrollTop: ratio});
})
```

Comment: can you write in on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: `/*i have implimented it like this please help */$(document).ready(function(){
    
   $('.scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
                        
   
$('.scrollbar1').scroll(function(){
var heightDiv = document.getElementById('.scrollbar1').clientHeight;
alert(heightDiv);
var height = document.body.offsetHeight;

jQuery(document).scroll(function(){

    var moved = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var ratio = moved*heightDiv*20/height;
    jQuery('.scrollbar1').animate({scrollTop: ratio});
})
});
});`